# Windows Phone 8.1 access file in Documents folder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm new to windows phone development, and not using silverlight or WPF.  I copy the file "links.txt" into my Windows Phone folder at "\Documents\" and I want to access and get the content in the file, but I'm getting back as access denied error.  I click on Package.appxmanifest file then select "Capabilities" tab, but I don't see "Documents Library Access" for me to check it.  As matter fact I don't see any "... Library Access" showing.  Below is the code:

```
string fileName = "\\Documents\\links.txt";
string parentPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
string filePath = Path.Combine(parentPath, fileName);
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
```

Any suggestion how can I read the file?  thanks.

Updates:

It seems the code above does not work, but when using the code below and change the folder to "Music" instead of "Documents" then check the Capabilities for "MusicLibrary", it's working.

```
 var folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
 var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("links.txt");
 var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are give the wrong filePath actual path is in this image

[image]

i try your code it shows same error so correct your file path

Comment: I change to this " string fileName = "C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\links.txt"; " but it has the same error, access denied.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked need `Capability` for Documents you should use [KnownFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) class instead `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`.

For example:

```
 StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary; 
 StorageFile file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: I'm unable to check the Documents in Capability because somehow my Visual Studio 2015 version does not show it.

Comment: I try your code suggestion, but without checking the Documents in Capability, and the same error access denied.